# ActiveRecord - #where method when field is a serialized empty array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord query:

```
Post.where(users: [])
```

In Rails 5.1.1, this results in:

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (users = '[]')
```

but in Rails 5.2.2, this results in:

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE 1=0
```

Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour in Rails 5.2 or a bug?

Comment: Why not just use a proper join table instead of a serialized array? Thats probably the worst possible design.

Comment: Are you able to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

**That is not a bug , 5.2.2 updated for remove SQL Injection problem.**

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (users = '[]')
```

If you observe this query we have a SQL Injection problem , that is if you pass some query instead of value then it will pass . It's too dangerous. You can use below code for to retrieve data based on array objects with where condition.

```
ModelName.where('users IN (?)', [array of elements] )
```

Comment: Can you explain more how this is a SQL inject problem? what do you mean by "query instead of value"?

Comment: But you can still do `Post.where(some_value: some_integer)`. My question is more about why we can no longer query for serialized arrays.

Comment: Follow "https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-ruby-on-rails-development/" this link . You will get better idea . If you have any doubt then comment me again .

Comment: You can use where condition with array like this
 ' Model.where('users IN (?)', [array of elements] ) '. From this we can grab all records of Model with array objects

Comment: So how can I get around this, I can now never use ActiveRecord's `#where` method when one of the fields is serialized...